# Calculate multiple cutoff percentages for an Int list in Haskell?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, statistics

I would like to write a Haskell function for the following problem: Given two list of Integers ("depths" and "thresholds"), return the mean depth and the fractional of depths greater or equal for each threshold.
As an example, given the depths `[10,10,10,15,15,20]` and the tresholds `[10,15,20]`, the expected result should be `[13.333333,1.0,0.5,0.16666667]` (mean depth is 13.3, 100% of depths >= 10, 50% of depths >= 15 & 17% of depths >=20).

An imperative pseudo code solution could look like this:

```
-- getMeanAndPercents (thresholds, depths):
--  sum = 0
--  threshold_counts = [0 for t in thresholds]
--  len = 0
--  for d in depths:
--   sum += d
--   len += 1
--   for t in thresholds:
--    if d >= t: tresholds_counts[t] += 1
--  for t in tresholds
--   threshold_percents[t] = thresholds_counts[t] / len
--  return = [sum / len] + [threshold_percents]
```

My Haskell solution looks like this:

```
getMeanAndPercents :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Float]
getMeanAndPercents thresholds depths = let
    depths2 = map f depths -- replace each depth d with [d, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, ...]
    counts = foldl1 (zipWith (+)) depths2 -- sum the inner lists
    len = fromIntegral $ length depths -- get total depth length
                                       in fromIntegral (head counts) / len : map (\c -> fromIntegral c / len) (tail counts)
    where
        f d = d : map (\t -> if d >= t then 1 else 0) thresholds
```

Questions:

1) How should this code be indented (I'm unsure how to mix `let ... in` with `where`)?

2) How often Haskell will loop over `depths`? I would assume once for `length` and once for `foldl1 & map`.

3) What would be a better (w.r.t. performance and/or readability)  implementation in Haskell? (I assume one needs to do at least `O(d*t)`, i.e. loop over all thresholds for all depths)

**EDIT:** The depths are not ordered, the thresholds could be ordered by the function. Thus, one could skip `>=` once the first threshold fails the test.

Comment: I find it rather weird that you put *average* in the same list as the percentages. I would use a 2-tuple with average the first, and percentages the second element.

Comment: I think there are some loose ends in the algorithm. Are the thresholds and their percentages related by the thresholds' quantity or value..?

Comment: Are the lists always ordered? You can do much better than `O(d*t)` if so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How should this code be indented?

That is subjective- personally I prefer this:

```hs
getMeanAndPercents :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Float]
getMeanAndPercents thresholds depths
  = let depths2 = map f depths
        counts  = foldl1 (zipWith (+)) depths2
        len     = fromIntegral $ length depths
    in fromIntegral (head counts) / len : map (\c -> fromIntegral c / len) (tail counts)
 where f d = d : map (\t -> if d >= t then 1 else 0) thresholds
```

#### How often Haskell will loop over depths? I would assume once for length and once for foldl1 & map.

Lists in Haskell are not actually lists, but rather lazy streams of data, like a generator in an imperative language like python.

Because the computation depends on the length of the stream, we have to go trough it once to see how long it is, which also forces you to load the entire list into memory.

You loop trough the depth list once for each item in the threshold list, and another time to get the sum, so this is `O(2d+dt)`.

If you actually know the length of the list you should pass it in to the function, or you could use another datatype like `Array` where the length is already known.

#### What would be a better (w.r.t. performance and/or readability) implementation in Haskell? (I assume one needs to do at least O(d*t), i.e. loop over all thresholds for all depths)

I would have written your implementation like this:

```hs
getMeanAndPercents :: [Int] -> [Int] -> (Float, [Float])
getMeanAndPercents thresholds depths
  | len    <- fi $ length depths
  , (c:cs) <- foldl1 (zipWith (+)) $ f <$> depths
  = (fi c / len, (/len).fi <$> cs)
 where f d = d : map (\t -> if d >= t then 1 else 0) thresholds
       fi  = fromIntegral
```

This is closer to your imperative code:

```hs
getMeanAndPercents thresholds depths
  | ((sum, len), ts) <- mapAccumL
      ( \(sum, len) d -> ( (sum+d, len+1)
                         , map (\t -> if d>=t then 1 else 0) thresholds
                         )
      ) (0,0) depths
  = (/len) <$> (sum:foldl1(zipWith(+))ts)
```

This is more readable/ideomatic haskell:

```hs
getMeanAndPercents :: [Int] -> [Int] -> (Float, [Float])
getMeanAndPercents thresholds depths
  | len <- length depths
  = ( sum depths / len
    , [ length (filter (>=t) depths) / len | t <- thresholds ]
    )
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it true that the ideomatic Haskell version loops over depths for every threshold and is thus slower or is the compiler able to do any magic here?

Comment: @Rolf No, it is only conceptually true. The compiler is arcane, and ideomatic haskell often outperforms C. In this particular case the ideomatic haskell code is orders of magnitude faster than the imperative one! (I tested both functions with 10000 depths and 10000 thresholds, the imperative one finished in `91.88s`, ideomatic haskell in `0.43s`)

Comment: Ah, thanks again! I also realize that it is conceptually the same to to loop over all thresholds for every depth or the other way around (in terms of Big O).